# WSL Ubuntu: after running a dotnet application which outputs to my console, the bash terminal output is messed up

Tags: bash, wsl2, ubuntu-20.04

[image]

There's no longer any line breaks and I can't see the results of me entering text. The application being run is my own and does nothing with the console except a couple of `Console.WriteLine` and `Console.ReadLine` calls.

Closing that terminal and opening a new one "solves" the issue.

How can I reset the behaviour in my current terminal? Also, how can I prevent this from happening?

Edit:

As requested, here are steps to recreate:

1. `git clone https://github.com/IanPNewson/Proxy`
2. `cd Proxy/ProxyServer`
3. `dotnet run {open port you have permission to}`, e.g. `dotnet run 4843`

Comment: If you can provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I'll try to reproduce.  Are you using Windows Terminal or the legacy console?  If you are on the older console (default for Windows 10), then you might want to try Windows Terminal to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I can do better than that! `git clone https://github.com/IanPNewson/Proxy` `cd Proxy/ProxyServer`, then `dotnet run {open port you have permission to}'. I'm using Windows Terminal.

Comment: Hmm - Also on Ubuntu 20.04 / WSL / Windows Terminal.  I was able to run it with no terminal glitches after exiting.  `dotnet --version` 6.0.201, Windows 11, Windows Terminal 1.11.3471.0, `TERM` is `xterm-256color`.  (Edit: Just did an `apt upgrade` and pulled in 6.0.202, but still no issues).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds thanks for checking. I've had weird glitches like this before which were solved with a brand new WSL instance so I'll just deal with this one for the time being. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure thing - If I think of anything else to try, I'll ping you.

Answer (score 1):

Typing `reset` solves the issue, but doesn't prevent it from happening again.